# How to solve Fractals over N-bars period in MQL4, similar to IQOptions Fractals indicator?

Tags: fractals, trading, algorithmic-trading, mql4

I am learning MQL4 myself. I registered with IQOptions for binary options trading.

I am planning to write some indicators myself for my trading system. I like fractals a lot, not from MQL4-supported fractal logic, but very keen on IQOptions specific one.

In MQL4, to find the fractal we use **`iFractal()`** which doesn't take any parameters other than an offset.

I convinced myself it just finds fractal over 3 bars. Doing a lot of homework, I have realized that IQOptions indicator is doing more than fractal. Please find the attached screenshot.

I wrote many programs to which I added a recent one below. I need some help to figure out what it has been there. The image I attached is from IQOption screenshot, with fractals over 20 bar period.

[image]

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                        Bulls.mq4 |
//|                   Copyright 2005-2014, MetaQuotes Software Corp. |
//|                                              http://www.mql4.com |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright   "2005-2014, MetaQuotes Software Corp."
#property link        "http://www.mql4.com"
#property description "Fractals Tanya"
#property strict

//--- indicator settings
#property indicator_chart_window
#property indicator_buffers 2
#property indicator_color1 Red
#property indicator_color2 Green
#property indicator_width1 1
#property indicator_width2 1
#property indicator_style1 STYLE_SOLID
#property indicator_style2 STYLE_SOLID
//--- input parameter
input int B_F=20;
//extern int AllB=240; 

//--- buffers
double ExtFractalsUPBuffer[];
double ExtFractalsDownBuffer[];

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator initialization function                         |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnInit(void)
  {

//--- 1 additional buffer used for counting.
   IndicatorBuffers(2);
   IndicatorDigits(Digits);
//--- indicator line
   SetIndexBuffer( 0, ExtFractalsUPBuffer );
   SetIndexStyle( 0, DRAW_ARROW );
   SetIndexArrow( 0, 234 ); 
   SetIndexLabel( 0, NULL );
   SetIndexEmptyValue( 0, 0.0 );

   SetIndexBuffer( 1, ExtFractalsDownBuffer );
   SetIndexStyle( 1, DRAW_ARROW );
   SetIndexArrow( 1, 233 ); 
   SetIndexLabel( 1, NULL );
   SetIndexEmptyValue( 1, 0.0 );

   SetIndexDrawBegin(0,B_F);
   SetIndexDrawBegin(1,B_F);

   IndicatorShortName( "FractalsTanya" );
   IndicatorDigits( Digits );
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Bulls Power                                                      |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
                const int prev_calculated,
                const datetime &time[],
                const double &open[],
                const double &high[],
                const double &low[],
                const double &close[],
                const long &tick_volume[],
                const long &volume[],
                const int &spread[])
  {

  int limit=rates_total-prev_calculated;
//---
   if(rates_total<=B_F || B_F<=0)
      return(0);
//---
   if(prev_calculated>0)
      limit++;
   int i=0,j=0,k=0;
   double upFratal=0.0;
   double downFratal=0.0;
   int x=0; int y=0;
    for(int t=0; t<limit+B_F; t++)
     {
     double upTempFractal=iFractals(NULL,Period(),MODE_UPPER,t);
     double downTempFractal=iFractals(NULL,Period(),MODE_LOWER,t);
     if(upTempFractal!=0&&upTempFractal>upFratal)
     {
      upFratal=upTempFractal;
      j=t;
     }
     if(downTempFractal!=0.0&&downFratal==0.0)
     {
         downFratal=downTempFractal;
     }
     if(downTempFractal!=0.0&&downTempFractal<=downFratal)
     {
         downFratal=downTempFractal;
         k=t;
     }
         i++;
         if(i==B_F)
         {
        if(upFratal!=0.0)
            {
            if(x==0||(j-x)>=B_F)
            {
              x=j;
              ExtFractalsUPBuffer[j]=upFratal;
            }
            }
            if(downFratal!=0.0)
            {
            if(y==0||(k-y)>=B_F)
            {
               y=k;
               ExtFractalsDownBuffer[k]=downFratal;
            }

            }
            i=0;
            upFratal=0.0;
            downFratal=0.0;
         }
     }

     /*for(int t=0; t<limit; t++)
     {
      double upFratal=iFractals(NULL,Period(),MODE_UPPER,t);
      double downFratal=iFractals(NULL,Period(),MODE_LOWER,t);
      if(upFratal!=0.0)ExtFractalsUPBuffer[t]=upFratal;
      else if(downFratal!=0.0)ExtFractalsDownBuffer[t]=downFratal;
     }*/
   return(rates_total);
  }
```

Comment: Could you clarify, what is your question -- what problem do you face in MCVE-of-code, with which you tried to solve some behaviour / feature, but your previous results did not show helpfull so far?

Comment: Actually, i solved it finally after going custom fractal methodology. The screenshot i posted is though desired behaviour I dont think its a real fractal logic. We can achieve that by finding a every (i+20/2) candle high/low value and checking if all i+20 to i+10 candles and i+10 to i candles highs/lows less than the i+10 candle high/low value

Answer (score 1):

I took the poster's code and changed it so that it will always give you the value of the last known up- and down fractal, no matter in which bar you're evaluating fractals. I imagine this could be very useful for anyone who reads this who needs this value at any given time.

```
#property copyright   "2021, EA Builder Pro"
#property link        "https://www.eabuilderpro.com"
#property description "Fractals always showing most recent value"
#property strict

#property indicator_chart_window
#property indicator_buffers 2
#property indicator_color1 Red
#property indicator_color2 Green
#property indicator_width1 1
#property indicator_width2 1
#property indicator_style1 STYLE_SOLID
#property indicator_style2 STYLE_SOLID

input int NumberOfBars=3;

double ExtFractalsUPBuffer[];
double ExtFractalsDownBuffer[];

void OnInit(void)
  {

   IndicatorBuffers(2);
   IndicatorDigits(Digits);

   SetIndexBuffer( 0, ExtFractalsUPBuffer );
   SetIndexStyle( 0, DRAW_ARROW );
   SetIndexArrow( 0, 234 ); 
   SetIndexLabel( 0, "Up" );
   SetIndexEmptyValue( 0, 0.0 );

   SetIndexBuffer( 1, ExtFractalsDownBuffer );
   SetIndexStyle( 1, DRAW_ARROW );
   SetIndexArrow( 1, 233 ); 
   SetIndexLabel( 1, "Down" );
   SetIndexEmptyValue( 1, 0.0 );

   SetIndexDrawBegin(0,NumberOfBars);
   SetIndexDrawBegin(1,NumberOfBars);

   IndicatorShortName( "FractalsEABuilderPro" );
   IndicatorDigits( Digits );
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Bulls Power                                                      |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
                const int prev_calculated,
                const datetime &time[],
                const double &open[],
                const double &high[],
                const double &low[],
                const double &close[],
                const long &tick_volume[],
                const long &volume[],
                const int &spread[])
{

   int limit=rates_total-prev_calculated;

   if (rates_total <= NumberOfBars || NumberOfBars <= 0)
      return(0);

   if (prev_calculated > 0)
      limit++;

   int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
   double upFractal = 0.0;
   double downFractal = 0.0;
   int x = 0; int y = 0;
   
   double mostRecentUpTempFractal = 0;
   double mostReceptDownTempFractal = 0;
   
   int lastUpPosition = 0;
   int lastDownPosition = 0;
   
   for (int b = 100 - NumberOfBars; b >= 0; b--)
   {
      double upTempFractal = iFractals(NULL,Period(),MODE_UPPER, b);
      double downTempFractal = iFractals(NULL,Period(),MODE_LOWER, b);
      
      if (upTempFractal != 0 && upTempFractal > upFractal)
      {
         upFractal = upTempFractal;
         j = b;
      }
      
      if (downTempFractal != 0.0 && downFractal == 0.0)
      {
         downFractal = downTempFractal;
      }
      
      if (downTempFractal != 0.0 && downTempFractal <= downFractal)
      {
         downFractal = downTempFractal;
         k = b;
      }
      
      i++;
      
      bool upValueSet = false;
      bool downValueSet = false;
      if (i == NumberOfBars)
      {
         if (upFractal != 0.0)
         {
            lastUpPosition = j;
 
            if (x == 0||(j-x) <= NumberOfBars)
            {
               x = j;
               ExtFractalsUPBuffer[j] = upFractal;
               mostRecentUpTempFractal = upFractal;
               upValueSet = true;
            }
         }
         
         if (downFractal != 0.0)
         {
            lastDownPosition = k;
                           
            if(y == 0 || (k - y) <= NumberOfBars)
            {
               y = k;
               ExtFractalsDownBuffer[k] = downFractal;
               mostReceptDownTempFractal = downFractal;
               downValueSet = true;
            }
         }
   
         i = 0;
         upFractal = 0.0;
         downFractal = 0.0;
      }
      
      if (!upValueSet && mostRecentUpTempFractal != 0.0)
      {
         lastUpPosition--;
         ExtFractalsUPBuffer[lastUpPosition] = mostRecentUpTempFractal;
         
      }
      
      if (!downValueSet && mostReceptDownTempFractal != 0.0)
      {
         lastDownPosition--;
         ExtFractalsDownBuffer[lastDownPosition] = mostReceptDownTempFractal;
      }
            
   }
     
   return(rates_total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that what you want to achieve is to find the fractals in the last X bars.
I had the same issue and in my case what I wanted to do was to find the most recent fractals, both up and down, this is the function I created. I used it to calculate a trailing stop.
Changing the function slightly you can find the highest and lowest fractals.

I hope this helps

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
bool   FractalsUp        = False;
bool   FractalsDown      = False;
double FractalsUpPrice   = 0;
double FractalsDownPrice = 0;

// -----------------------------------------------Number of bars to scan
int    FractalsLimit     = 15;

void FindFractals(){
// ------------------------------------------(re)-Initialization of the variables
   FractalsUp        = False;
   FractalsDown      = False;
   FractalsUpPrice   = 0;
   FractalsDownPrice = 0;
/* --------------------------------------A for(){...} loop to scan
                                                      the last FractalsLimit
                                                      candles, starting from
                                                      the oldest and finishing
                                                      with the most recent one */
   for ( int i = FractalsLimit; i >= 0; i-- ){
      // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
         double fu = iFractals( NULL, 0, MODE_UPPER, i );
         double fl = iFractals( NULL, 0, MODE_LOWER, i );
                                             /* If there is a POSACK of fractal on the candle
                                                   the value will be greater than zero
                                                   and equal to the highest or lowest price */
      // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
         if (  fu >  0 ){                    // If there is an upper fractal
               FractalsUpPrice   = fu;       //    store the value and
               FractalsUp        = True;     //    set True the FractalsUp variable
               FractalsDown      = False;    //    set False on POSACK_UP
         }
      // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
         if (  fl >  0 ){                    // If there is an lower fractal
               FractalsDownPrice = fl;       //    store the value and
               FractalsUp        = False;    //    set False on POSACK_LO
               FractalsDown      = True;     //    set True the FractalsDown variable
         }
      // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
         if (  fu >  0                       // If the candle has both upper
            && fl >  0                       //    and lower fractal
               ){
               FractalsUpPrice   = fu;       //    the values are stored 
               FractalsDownPrice = fl;
               FractalsUp        = False;    //    but we do not, on NACK,
               FractalsDown      = False;    //    consider it as last fractal
         }
   }
}
```